# Image with hyperlink - clickable area exceeds image

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink, gallery

I have an issue with the galleries on my WordPress website: each image in the gallery has a clickable area that exceeds the image. For example, if I have a gallery with only one image, the hyperlink extends both left and right of the image for the whole length of the content. I only want the hyperlink over the image itself, I don't want the image to open when clicking anywhere to the left or right of it. (example gallery: https://blog.ovidiuav.com/2018/11/09/nou-autor-blog/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/10283047.

Comment: `display: inline-block` for the `a` around the `img` element fixes most of the problem already. If the remaining “linked” space beneath is a concern as well, then you need to remove the `margin-bottom` from the images, and put it somewhere else (like on the link, or the container element.)

Comment: Thank you @misorude, that worked and I updated the question with the solution. I was not aware of that rule but I understand it, thank you for pointing it out. However, in this case, I didn't have any actual code to post. I did, however, post the code that solved the issue in the question for anyone who might be interested. Thanks again!

P.S. Could you post again as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS fixed it:

```
.gallery .gallery-icon img {
display: inline-block;
}
```

*(suggestion from misorude in a comment to the question)*

Answer (score 0):

Add this following to your css file,

```
.gallery-icon{
width: fit-content;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work, though. I got an answer in the meantime, I've updated the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell where the actual issue is without any code, use an anchor element wrapping the image perhaps? And adjusting the image to your required size.

```html
<a href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank">
  <img class="image" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg" title="Butterfly">
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got an answer in the meantime, I've updated the question with the solution.